# Implements children changes on ListView. OnHierarchyChangeListener?

Tags: android, listview, listener, android-view

I extend a ListView and I would like to track its children's heights (and put it into a dictionary). However the `implements OnHierarchyChangeListener` does not work. Am I using a wrong listener or have missed something?

```
public class ObservableListView extends ListView implements OnHierarchyChangeListener {
    //constructors
    private Dictionary<Integer, Integer> listViewItemHeights = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();

    private void updateItemHeights(){    
        System.out.println("updating items");           
        for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); ++i) {
            View c = getChildAt(i);
            if(c!=null)
                listViewItemHeights.put(this.getFirstVisiblePosition(), c.getHeight());         
        }           
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildViewAdded(View arg0, View arg1) {
        updateItemHeights();
    }    

    @Override
    public void onChildViewRemoved(View arg0, View arg1) {
        updateItemHeights();
    }

    //Other methods
}
```

Comment: @pskink I'm adding items via an adapter and `System.out.println("updating items");` is never displayed.

Comment: now better, did you call setOnHierarchyChangeListener ?

Comment: @pskink No. `mList.setOnHierarchyChangeListener( mList );` right?

Comment: in ObservableListView constructor call setOnHierarchyChangeListener(this)

Comment: @pskink thanks, add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually set the listener, which I would suggest you do in the constructor of your ListView class, like this (all three of them, just to be safe):

```
public ObservableListView(Context context){
    super(context);
    prepareView();
}

public ObservableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    prepareView();
} 

public ObservableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, Map params){
    super(context, attrs, params);
    prepareView();
} 

private void prepareView(){
    setOnHierarchyChangedListener(this);
}
```

Just copy this code into your ObservableListView class, right before updateItemHeights and it should work.

Comment: Question, why not calling `setOnHierarchyChangedListener(this);` directly in the constructors and have to create a new `prepareView()` method?

Comment: @Diolor You can of course do it that way if you prefer, I just suggest  creating a new method for the sake of any possible future setup actions you would want to perform in the constructor of your custom ListView, without having to copy/paste the code. Like add some additional listener perhaps, if you later wanted to listen for scroll events, you would simply make the ObservableListView implement AbsListView.OnScrollListener, and then add another call to your prepareView() method, setOnScrollListener(this). Something along those lines.